# dracut md5sum boot directory

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, initramfs

This has been going on for a few months now, but my initramfs (and kernel) for that matter have been placed in `/boot/{some hash}/{kernel version}/{initramfs,linux}`.

Did dracut or some other module change to cause this behavior?

I don't use the grub update tool to update my grub configuration as it caused some issues with missing a bracket `{` and then I wouldn't be able to boot.  Is this somehow related to that or are these separate changes / problems?